# Cleaner way to remove 2nd word from string. Currently using split, splice, then join

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function to always remove the 2nd word from a sentence.

```
public cleanMessage(message) {
    let cleanedMessage: any = message.split(' ');
    cleanedMessage.splice(1, 1);
    cleanedMessage = cleanedMessage.join(' ');
    return cleanedMessage;
  }

cleanMessage('Hello there world')
// outputs 'Hello world'
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: This is perfectly readable. You don't need to change it.

Comment: also, why are you using typescript without types?

Comment: `return message.split(' ').reduce((f, i, idx) => idx !== 1 `${f} ${i}` : f,'');` <-- using `.reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to shorten it, you can use regex:

`(?<=\S)\s\S+` will take out the second word in the string

- `(?<=\S)` creates a lookbehind for a word
- `\s\S+` selects a space with a word after it

You can then remove this space + word with:

```js
public cleanMessage(message) {
  return message.replace(/(?<=\S)\s\S+/, '');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexp is indeed shorter and IMO easier to read as long as you use simpler operators.

```
string.replace(/^(\S+)\s+\S+/, '$1')
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | from beginning of string |
| `(\S+)` | take and remember non-spaces - 1st word |
| `\s+` | followed by spaces |
| `\S+` | and another word |
| `$1` | replace with remembered first word |

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is already pretty much as clean as possible.

You could write it a little shorter maybe like:

```js
public cleanMessage = (message) => message
  .split(' ')
  .filter((word, i) => i !== 1)
  .join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the regexp solutions, but here's another one that's kind of obvious.

```js
const cleanMessage = (message) => {
  const [first, second, ...rest] = message.split(' ');
  return [first, rest].flat().join(' ');
};

console.log(cleanMessage("Hello world, I'm here!"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more potential way using Array `reduce`:

```
const cleanMessage = message => (
  message.split(' ').reduce(
    (f, i, idx) => idx === 1 ? f : f + ' ' + i, ''
  )
);
```

**Explanation**

- Use `split` to obtain an array of words (ie, separated by space)
- Use `reduce` to iterate through the words and skip the word at index `1`.

**Code snippet**

```js
const cleanMessage = message => (
  message.split(' ').reduce(
    (f, i, idx) => idx === 1 ? f : f + ' ' + i
  )
);

console.log(cleanMessage('Hello there world!'));
```